# How to fix the jquery code below

Tags: jquery

```
<h1>Click me</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.content').hide();
var $this = $('h1');``

var form = {

    enter: function(){
        console.log('slideDown')
            // $this.next('div.content').slideDown(500)     
    },

    leave: function(){
        console.log('slideUp')
            // $this.next('div.content').slideUp(500)       
    }

}

$this.mouseenter(function(){
    form.enter();
})
$this.mouseleave(function(){
    form.leave();
})
</script>
</body>
```

In this code, i want that when i mouse enter the 'click me' then it will slide down the '.content' class and when mouse leave it will slide up it. but in this case when i mouse enter it slide downs and slide ups three times at once but when mouse  leave it slide ups actually one time. so how can i fix it? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the animation triggering multiple times by checking to see if the element is hidden before you do the `slideDown`, and checking if it's visible before you do the `slideUp`.

Here's the code for that:

```
enter: function(){
    console.log('slideDown');
    if ($this.next('div.content').is(":hidden")) {
        $this.next('div.content').slideDown(500);
    }
},

leave: function(){
    console.log('slideUp');
    if ($this.next('div.content').is(":visible")) {
        $this.next('div.content').slideUp(500); 
    }
}
```

**Working Live Demo:**

```js
$('.content').hide();
var $this = $('h1');``

var form = {

    enter: function(){
        console.log('slideDown');
        if ($this.next('div.content').is(":hidden")) {
            $this.next('div.content').slideDown(500);
        }
    },

    leave: function(){
        console.log('slideUp');
        if ($this.next('div.content').is(":visible")) {
            $this.next('div.content').slideUp(500); 
        }
    }

}

$this.mouseenter(function(){
    form.enter();
})
$this.mouseleave(function(){
    form.leave();
})
```

```css
.content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click me</h1>
<div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat nonproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Maximillian Laumeister (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2234742/maximillian-laumeister) for your kind help..

Comment: @smkpobon Glad I could help! Unless there is anything else you need help with in reference to this problem, please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted using the gray checkmark. Thanks!

Comment: ok... and thanks again. actually i'm new in stackoverflow and a novice in programming in jquery  @Maximillian_Laumeister

Comment: please help to understand the code have in this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044336/need-help-to-understand-the-below-jquery-code]

Comment: Explain this code in the link below please: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044336/need-help-to-understand-the-below-jquery-code)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.content').hide()` is not the same as `$('.content').slideDown()`, so you can't use one to set up the state of another.

Try:

```
  $('.content').slideDown();
  var $this = $('h1');`
```