# need help to understand the below jquery code

Tags: jquery

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#blog">Blog</a>

<div id="home"> Volutpat wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto</div>
<div id="blog"> Volutpat wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto</div>

$('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 1000);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
```

This code is for smooth scrolling clicking on the home,blog link. But i can't understand the jquery section. what's the meaning of this ->

```
$('a[href*=#]')
```

and this->

```
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
```

please help me. i'm a novice in jquery..

Comment: **[`Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

Comment: `$.attr(this, 'href') === $(this).attr("href")`

Comment: It's similar to 'LIKE'. $('a[href*=#]') means attach handler to href which contain #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('a[href*=#]')` selects all `a` elements that have an `href` attribute (`[]` matches attributes) that contains (`*=` is the contains matcher) a `#`.

This means the scrolling of all links that are on the same page (as they are anchor-based) is animated.

---

`scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top` picks the offset (`.offset()`) to the top of the page (`.top`) of the target the clicked link points to (`$($.attr(this, 'href))`) and scrolls to this position.

Comment: is that means when i click  a link the ( `.offset()` ) takes the page back to top and then scrolls back to the position pointed by the clicked link ??  and also describe what  `.offset()` does .  thanks

Comment: No, it just looks where the position is and scrolls to it. [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) "get[s] the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.".